# Get hostname of another node in docker bridge network from it's IP address

Tags: docker, containers

From inside a docker container, what command can I use to get the **hostname** of another container that is on the same bridge network from it's IP address?

**For example:**

```
[root@my-container ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      my-container
172.17.0.5      another-container
```

How can I get the result `another-container` from `172.17.0.5`?

*Note: The following doesn't work.*

```
[root@my-container ~]# host 172.17.0.5
Host 5.0.17.172.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're starting the containers? When I tested two containers on a user-defined network `host <ip-address>` correctly returns the matching container hostname. Remember that if you're on the default docker bridge network, there is no docker-maintained DNS.

Comment: Thanks, @larsks. That may be my problem.  I have been using the default bridge network.